# Join Clause With a XOR Statement

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2000, xor

I am doing a join and I can't seem to make this XOR to properly work.

```
SELECT t1.COMPANY, t1.MILES,
   CASE WHEN t2.MILES IS NULL THEN t3.MILES
        ELSE t2.MILES
   END AS MILES2,
   CASE WHEN t2.MILES = t1.MILES AND t2.MILES != 9999 THEN t2.FLATRATE
        ELSE t3.RATEBASIS
   END AS RATE           
FROM TABLE1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS t2 
        ON t1.[COMPANY] = t2.[COMPANYCODE] AND (t1.[MILES] = t2.[MILES])
    INNER JOIN (
         SELECT TOP 1 TRUCKERCODE, MILES, RATEBASIS, FLATRATE FROM TABLE2 WHERE MILES = 9999
               ) AS t3 
   ON t1.[COMPANY] = t3.[COMPANYCODE]
```

I need the ON clause to join if the miles are the same then get the given fields that match otherwise the default data I need to get out of the second table is where the miles is equal to 9999. Right now with that ON clause I get many extra rows where the MILES equals lets say 45, it gets the data from TABLE2 where miles equals 45 and all the data where miles equals 9999. I need it to do one or the other but not both. This is what my tables would look like

```
TABLE1                          TABLE2
ID COMPANY MILES ETC            ID COMPANYCODE MILES RATE
1  ILLINI  50                   1  ILLINI      50    3.2
2  ILLINI  110                  2  ILLINI      110   5.2
3  ILLINI  150                  3  ILLINI      150   2.4
4  ILLINI  200                  4  ILLINI      200   1.9
5  ILLINI  250                  5  ILLINI      9999  1.5
6  ILLINI  300                       
7  ILLINI  350
8  ILLINI  400
9  ILLINI  450
10 ILLINI  500

Desired Output
COMPANY MILES MILES2 RATE
ILLINI  50    50    3.2
ILLINI  110   110   5.2
ILLINI  150   150   2.4
ILLINI  200   200   1.9
ILLINI  250   9999  1.5
ILLINI  300   9999  1.5                    
ILLINI  350   9999  1.5
ILLINI  400   9999  1.5
ILLINI  450   9999  1.5
ILLINI  500   9999  1.5
```

Comment: Why is, e.g., `ILLINI  150 150   2.4` excluded from the output?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I just gave a quick version. Of course that would be included in the output. It would have a total of 10 different output. I was just giving an example.

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error when applying my query in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you what you want:

```
SELECT t1.COMPANY, t1.MILES,
       CASE WHEN t2.MILES IS NULL THEN t3.MILES
            ELSE t2.MILES
       END AS MILES2,
       CASE WHEN t2.MILES IS NULL THEN t3.RATE
            ELSE t2.RATE
       END AS RATE           
FROM TABLE1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS t2 
   ON t1.[COMPANY] = t2.[COMPANYCODE] AND (t1.[MILES] = t2.[MILES])
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT TOP 1 COMPANYCODE, MILES, RATE FROM TABLE2 WHERE MILES = 9999
) AS t3 
   ON t1.[COMPANY] = t3.[COMPANYCODE]
```

If there is a match in `MILES`, then output contains both records from `TABLE1`, `TABLE2`. Otherwise, output contains record from left table, i.e. `TABLE1` and the *specific* record from `TABLE2` with `MILES = 9999`.

Please note that `TOP 1` is used in the last sub-query just in case *more than one records* with `MILES = 9999` exist in `TABLE2`.

**Output:**

```
COMPANY MILES   MILES2  RATE
----------------------------
ILLINI  50      50      3,2
ILLINI  110     110     5,2
ILLINI  150     150     2,4
ILLINI  200     200     1,9
ILLINI  250     9999    1,5
ILLINI  300     9999    1,5
ILLINI  350     9999    1,5
ILLINI  400     9999    1,5
ILLINI  450     9999    1,5
ILLINI  500     9999    1,5
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/033b1/1)

Comment: Can you explain to me what the second inner join is doing? I understand how the first Left Join is working. How does the statement know when to or when not to fire off the Inner Join?

Comment: @Kyle The second `INNER JOIN` is always "fired": it joins the `9999` record of `TABLE2` to each and every record of `TABLE1`. Using `CASE` we can choose whether to include this `9999` record to our output or not.

Comment: Ok the SQL is not getting the data that the Miles don't match. So it is getting the 50, 110, 150, and 200 but 250 and beyond it doesn't grab them from my table.

Comment: @Kyle In this case there is sth in your real environment that you have not told us about. The output produced from my query based on the sample data provided in the OP is identical to the required one.

Comment: How different is the SQL from 2000 and 2008?

Comment: @Kyle Are you getting a syntax error when applying my query in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: No I don't get a error, It just doesn't print out the higher values unless the miles for both tables match.

Comment: @Kyle What are *higher* values? This is something not implied in the requirements as stated in the OP.

Comment: @Kyle Do you want to fetch the *higher* value from `TABLE2` or do you want to fetch `9999` (as stated in the OP)?

Comment: The higher values are the ones like 250 and so one. If the miles don't match then it ignores them instead of pairing 250 with 9999

Comment: @Kyle In this case the only thing I can think of is that you have mistyped the query. Did you check the SQL Fiddle I attached?

Comment: I am having a hard time putting that Query into my bigger query. I can't tell where the issue is in the syntax because it is big.

Comment: @Kyle You could strip down your bigger query to what is necessary to reproduce the error you get and try posting a different question in SO.

Comment: I just made a need stack overflow with my big SQL statement that I have been trying to break it down.

Answer (score 0):

I would do based on a double left-join.. once for a match, and if not, then default to the 9999 instance

```
SELECT
      T1.*,
      coalesce( T2.miles, T3.miles ) as Miles2,
      coalesce( T2.rate, T3.rate ) as MileageRate
   FROM
      TABLE1 T1
         LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
            on T1.Company = T2.CompanyCode
           AND T1.Miles = T2.Miles
         LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T3
            on T1.Company = T3.CompanyCode
           AND T3.Miles = 9999
```

Confirmed working [at this SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/033b1/2)

Comment: With yours, when I run it with my database it returns a lot of null values for Miles2 and MileageRate. If the miles match it will print out the correct Miles2 and MileageRate.

Comment: @Kyle, I don't know if you got it before my last edit... the second LEFT JOIN was to join the T3.miles, not T2.miles.  Can you confirm and let me know.

Comment: The SQL query that I am using is exactly the same as the one you have above

Comment: @Kyle, I just tried and posted a link to SQL Fiddle based on the same data / schema that Giorgos provided and shows no NULL values

Comment: 816.0 NULL NULL
788.0 NULL NULL
1812.0 NULL NULL
0.0         NULL NULL
79.0         NULL       NULL
117.0 NULL NULL
175.0 NULL NULL
798.0 NULL NULL
1230.0 NULL NULL
681.0 NULL     NULL   This is what I get