# SQL Query Not Working Properly With Multiple Join Clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on this Query for quite a while. I just got a resolution for part of it and now trying to add that query to my big one, I am having some problems with the output of the query.

```
SELECT T1.[miles], 
       T2.[name], 
       T2.[code], 
       T2.[routesid], 
       T2.[id], 
       T2.[company], 
       T2.[contract], 
       T2.[supplier], 
       T3.[tons], 
       CASE 
         WHEN T4.miles IS NULL THEN T5.miles 
         ELSE T4.miles 
       END MILES2, 
       CASE 
         WHEN T4.miles = T1.miles 
              AND T4.miles != 9999 THEN T4.flatrate 
         ELSE T5.rate 
       END AS RATE, 
       T3.[change] 
FROM   ((table1 AS T1 
         JOIN table2 AS T2 
           ON T1.[company] = T2.[company] 
              AND T1.[id] = T2.[routesid]) 
        JOIN table3 AS T3 
          ON T1.[company] = T3.[code]) 
       LEFT JOIN table4 AS T4 
              ON T1.[company] = T4.[code] 
                 AND ( T1.[miles] = T4.[miles] ) 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 code, 
                                miles, 
                                rate, 
                                flatrate 
                   FROM   table4 
                   WHERE  miles = 9999 
                          AND active = 1) AS T5 
               ON T1.[company] = T5.[code] 
WHERE  T2.[active] = 1 
       AND T2.[expiration] < '02/10/2015' 
       AND T1.[miles] > 0 
       AND T1.[company] = 'COMPANY' 
       AND T3.[active] = 1;
```

I know its a big query. I am trying to figure out why it leaves out the numbers that would pair with the miles on table 4 where it pair with 9999. It has no problem printing out these.

```
MILES NAME CODE ROUTESID ID   COMPANY CONTACT SUPPLIER TONS MILES2 CHANGE
140   N/A  N/A  3425     185  ILLINI  TARIFF 1 N/A      24  140    Weekly
144   N/A  N/A  4532     198  ILLINI  TARIFF 3 N/A      24  144    Weekly
9999  N/A  N/A  2134     150  ILLINI  TARIFF 2 N/A      24  9999   Weekly
```

Its not printing out right now if it matches this case below. Which I got the SQL statement from my previous stack overflow, I got the SQL statement to print if Miles and Miles2 don't match but since I added the SQLs together it stopped working.

```
MILES NAME CODE ROUTESID ID   COMPANY CONTACT SUPPLIER TONS MILES2 CHANGE
140   N/A  N/A  3420     170  ILLINI  TARIFF 4 N/A      24  9999   Weekly
```

[Previous Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412714/join-clause-with-a-xor-statement/28413564?noredirect=1#comment45209592_28413564)

[Here is a demo of the issue](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fb398/1)
As you can see the 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, and 500 out of TABLE1 isn't displaying.

[Here is the resolution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fb398/3)

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: 1) Formatting your code to be human-readable will go a long way to allowing humans to read and understand it.  2) Can you be more specific about the problem you're facing?

Comment: Are you joking? This isn't even readable.

Comment: Well, your problem most likely is that you are joining with a `TOP 1` from table4 (and no `ORDER BY`), that means that you are always joining with one particular row

Comment: This really isn't a big query. It is however awfully hard to figure out what you are doing with nothing but a query.

Comment: @Lamak The OP wants to output this exact record from `TABLE4` in case the preceding `LEFT JOIN` operation returns `NULL`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a small sample of records from tables `TABLE1`, `TABLE2`, `TABLE3` and `TABLE4`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos It would be helpful if op also post the results that s/he is getting and the results s/he wants to get

Comment: @Lamak The desired results are cited on the referred SO post. The results s/he is getting are just those records for which `LEFT JOIN` returns `T4.miles` which are `NOT NULL` (I hope I did not confuse you :-))

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I didn't actually read the previous question, since I think that every question should at least be self contained.

Comment: As a first debug step I would first leave out the last `INNER JOIN`, then the preceding `LEFT JOIN`. What results do you get in these two cases?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos , If I take out the inner join it prints out the same thing. If I take out the SQL query you helped with It shows all the miles that I need without Left Join. Like I see miles = 820, 292, 310, and etc.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If you take out: `INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 code, ...` then what results do you get?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I get the same results.

Comment: if you take out `LEFT JOIN table4 AS T4 ...` *and* `INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 code, ...` ?

Comment: All my data appears.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I just added a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by Giorgos in your previous Stack Overflow thread worked partially because you only had one company in your example. See this portion of the query?:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 code, 
                            miles, 
                            rate, 
                            flatrate 
               FROM   table4 
               WHERE  miles = 9999 
                      AND active = 1) AS T5 
ON T1.[company] = T5.[code]
```

This literally takes only the top row from the table (where miles = 9999 and active = 1) and then tries to join it to the T1 table. Not the top row for each company, just the top row. So whatever company happens to be on the top row is the only one available when you join the T5 table to the T1 table on the company field. You could get around this perhaps by using distinct instead of top 1, if the table doesn't have multiple rows for a single code where miles = 9999 and active = 1 (which I'm guessing you shouldn't, as that would mean there are multiple rates for the same code and miles):

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT distinct code, miles, rate, flatrate 
            FROM   table4 
            WHERE  miles = 9999 AND active = 1
            GROUP BY code) AS T5 ON T1.[company] = T5.[code]
```

But as others have noted, it is very difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish, partially because the formatting of your query is odd.  And it would help perhaps to re-explain the nature of your tables and the solution you are seeking, as well as defining the problem better.

Comment: Maybe my Demo is better at describing it.

Comment: Ok, I think the issue is that you put AND T4.[active] = 1 in the where clause of the query. That removes any rows that don't have a value of 1 for t4.active. Many of your rows have a null value for this field because you did a left outer join on t4. You can add the AND T4.[active] = 1 to the join criteria for the t4 table instead.